# TXT File verification on shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a shell script that does certain process on txt files only if it does exist, however this test loop doesn't work, I wonder why? Thank you!

`while [ -e '*.txt' ]
do
        $process
done`

Comment: Do you actually want to test whether a file named `*.txt` exists?  Because that's what your code is doing.

Answer (score 3):

Your `while` loop (once fixed) will run `$process` continuously, until all files named `*.txt` have been deleted. I don't see how that would be useful.

I'm guessing -- guessing, mind you -- that you intended to do something like this instead:

```
for f in *.txt; do $process; done
```

This will invoke `$process` once for each `.txt` file, setting `$f` to the name of the file. For instance,

```
for f in *.txt; do cat $f; done
```

will output the contents of each `.txt` file in the current directory.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your reply. I don't want to use "for", I really need fix my while loop as I described. Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If all on one line, your commands need semicolons as follows:

```
while [ -e '*.txt' ] ; do $process ; done
```

However, I don't think that [ -e '*.txt' ] does what you want.  It looks for a file literally named '*.txt'.

It is not a neat solution, but this seems to work:

```
while stat --format='' *.txt >/dev/null 2>/dev/null  ; do $process ; done
```

One could probably use *find* or some other command instead of *stat,* but the idea is to pick a command that returns true if and only if at least one argument is supplied.  Best would be to write your own command that returned 0 or 1 depending on *argc.*

However, also see @Thomas' reply.  One suspects that his guess may be right.

*Update:*  Here is a better answer:

```
at_least_one() { (($# > 0)) ; }
while at_least_one *.txt ; do $process ; done
```